# How to get the ID for the specified custom object record form visual force page to apex class?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, visualforce

I'm trying to do a small project and I am stuck as I couldn't pull out the ID of the specified record of a custom object from vf page to apex class the code is given below

```
<apex:page   standardController="enquiry__c" extensions='callme' recordSetVar="items"> <!--here enquiry__c is a custom object -->
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock>
            <apex:pageblocksection>
               <apex:pageBlockTable value='{!items}' var='en' width="200"  >
                   <apex:column value='{!en.name}'/>
                   <apex:column value='{!en.Student_Enquiry_Name__c}'/>
                   <apex:column value='{!en.phone__c}'/>
                   <apex:column value='{!en.email__c}'/>
                   <apex:column value='{!en.Status__c}'/>
                   <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                       <apex:commandButton value='convert to student'/>
                   </apex:column>  
                   <apex:column headerValue="Record ID">
                       <apex:outputText value='{!en.id}'  />
                   </apex:column>
                  
               </apex:pageBlockTable> 
                <apex:commandButton value='new' action='{!newenquiry}'/>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And the output is as below
[image]

So my question is when I click on button "**convert to student**" beside a particular record I have to get the ID of that record into apex class and the apex code is given below

```
public class callme
{
    public enquiry__c e {get;set;}
    public id i {get;set;}
    public callme(ApexPages.StandardSetController c)
    {
        
        
    }
     public PageReference newenquiry()
    {
        PageReference p=new PageReference('/apex/vfTab_on_enquiry');
        return p;
    }
    public PageReference newcourse()
    {
        PageReference p=new PageReference('/apex/courseInsertion');
        return p;
    }
}
```

Please help me with this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

-> you can use actionFunction for this.

-> create a js function called callActionMethod and invoke this function on the click of "convert to student" button.

-> create convertStudent method in apex class.

-> create an actionfunction named callConvertStudentMethod and pass the record id to the parameter.

Apex Controller:

```
public class callme
{
    public enquiry__c e {get;set;}
    public id i {get;set;}
    public callme(ApexPages.StandardSetController c)
    {
        e = new enquiry__c();
        
    }
     public PageReference newenquiry()
    {
        PageReference p=new PageReference('/apex/vfTab_on_enquiry');
        return p;
    }
    public PageReference newcourse()
    {
        PageReference p=new PageReference('/apex/courseInsertion');
        return p;
    }
    public void convertStudent(){
        system.debug('record id ---->'+i);
        e = [SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM enquiry__c WHERE ID = :i]; 
        system.debug('student record ---->'+e);
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page   standardController="enquiry__c" extensions='callme' recordSetVar="items"> <!--here enquiry__c is a custom object -->
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock id='resultPanel'>
            <apex:pageblocksection>
               <apex:pageBlockTable value='{!items}' var='en' width="200"  >
                   <apex:column value='{!en.name}'/>
                   <apex:column value='{!en.Student_Enquiry_Name__c}'/>
                   <apex:column value='{!en.phone__c}'/>
                   <apex:column value='{!en.email__c}'/>
                   <apex:column value='{!en.Status__c}'/>
                   <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                       <apex:commandButton value='convert to student' onclick="callActionMethod({!en.id})" />
                   </apex:column>  
                   <apex:column headerValue="Record ID">
                       <apex:outputText value='{!en.id}'  />
                   </apex:column>
                  
               </apex:pageBlockTable> 
                <apex:commandButton value='new' action='{!newenquiry}'/>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
        <apex:actionFunction name="callConvertStudentMethod" action="{!convertStudent}" reRender="resultPanel" >
            <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!i}" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>

    </apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function callActionMethod(ele)
        {

           callConvertStudentMethod(ele);

        }

    </script>
</apex:page>
```